# Replace cell value on a condition

Tags: sql

If a patient comes to the hospital 3 times and at one time the discharge status is died and 2 times it is survived. I want to write a code where in all the visit if the status is died then the final status should be died.

| PatientName | PatientVisit | DischargeStatus | FinalStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | Survived | Survived |
| A | 2 | Survived | Survived |
| A | 3 | Survived | Survived |
| B | 1 | Died | Died |
| B | 2 | Survived | Died |

Thanks.

Comment: I can't understand well your question here. Why there are two DischargeStatus?  Where is the final status? Please improve the question to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry just updated the column name. Thanks

Comment: Hi @rafavilomar, If the status of the patient is died in one of the visits then a new column will just show died for all his journey and not for one visit only? As i have to add this to pre exiting view, can you suggest something to add in the view please so that i can create a new column with the updated status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my limited experience with SQL, I think you should execute this:

`UPDATE Patient SET FinalStatus = 'Died' WHERE PatientName in (SELECT name FROM (SELECT PatientName AS name FROM Patient WHERE DischargeStatus = 'Died') AS a);`

Since we can’t specify target table ‘Patient’ for update in FROM clause, so here I add an inner table 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the table name is Patient, so you can do something like:

`UPDATE Patient SET FinalStatus = 'Died' WHERE DischargeStatus = 'Died'`

When you execute this SQL query, if any patient has a DischargeStatus like 'Died', it will be the same for the FinalStatus.

You can learn more about it [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

If you want to combine some validations to maybe include the PatientVisit column, you can use the `AND` or `OR` operator just like [HERE](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/where-and-or-not)

Comment: Adding/editing for one column is what I understand. I have a confusion for the part where i have to change for the whole patient journey. If the status of the patient is died in one of the visits then a new column will just show died for all his journey and not for one visit only.

Comment: Hi @rafavilomar, If the status of the patient is died in one of the visits then a new column will just show died for all his journey and not for one visit only? As i have to add this to pre exiting view, can you suggest something to add in the view please so that i can create a new column with the updated status?